# If Java Annotation doesn't have business logic on it, then how does @Entity in JavaEE could map a class in database?

Tags: java, annotations

I read somewhere that annotations are only metadata and do not contain any business logic.

So I look at the code of @Entity annotation:

```
package javax.persistence;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Entity {
    String name() default "";
}
```

Now, how this code could map a class to a database without a method define on it?

Comment: Maybe you should add the source of that statement, so it can be put into context.

Comment: @Sweeper No, it is not Annotation Processing.

Answer (score 2):

`@Entity` itself has no logic but a specification.
The business logic is implement by third party code.

For example, if you are using Spring Boot, you can follow the class `@EntityScan` to see how it handle `@Entity` classes.